# Access R file functions from .Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm new in R and Rstudio and I'm making a little project. The fact is that i have on one hand an .R file with the code I want to execute. And on the other hand I've an .Rmd file that I should use to report my work, including the results of the execution of my code in the other file.

How can I access the results and/or functions from de .Rmd file to the .R file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

By default, your `.Rmd` file will have its working directory as wherever the `.Rmd` file is saved. You can use all of R's standard functions inside the `.Rmd` file, including  `source()` to run a `.R` file. So if your files are in the same directory, you can include `source("your_r_file.R")` to run the `.R` file. If they are in different directories, you can use relative or absolute file paths (though you should try to avoid absolute file paths in case the `.Rmd` file is ever run on a different computer).

If you are using RStudio, I would strongly recommend using the "Projects" feature and the `here` package. [The readme for the `here` package is quite good for explaining its benefits](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here).

Answer (score 0):

Source the R file in at the top of your .Rmd file like

````
```{r}
source("file-name.R")
```
````

and the functions/objects in that R file will be avilable